# Are there any declarations of canonisation (Saints) reversed in history in the RCC?

Tags: catholicism

Is it possible to annihilate or reverse a sacrificing of 'holy' person by another Pope and is this ever been done?

Comment: I suspect there is a mistake in your question. You probably mean canonisation instead of sacrifice.